# Javascriptを利用したメニューのサンプルコードについて、jsファイルが読み込まれない

Tags: javascript

初心者です
サンプルコードを実行したところ、HTMLとCSSは機能していますが、スニペットから外部ファイルのjsファイルが機能していません。Google chromeのF12で確認しましたが、エラーは出ていません。何が問題なのかわかりません。
どなたかご教示頂ければ幸いです。

サンプルコードの引用先は下記の
https://digipress.info/tech/3d-rotating-hidden-menu-sample/　で一番下のサンプルです。

```
　<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
```

```js
var mqWidth = 680,
    scrollTrigger = 40,
    isMobile = null,
    burgerCheckbox = $('#humberger_check'), 
    hiddenMenu = $('.hidden_menu li'),
    slideBar = $('.menu_underline'),
    headerBar = $('.header_bar');

function sliderBarAnimation(){
  if ( $(window).width() > mqWidth ){
    if (isMobile === false) return;
    isMobile = false;
    hiddenMenu.off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(
      // nmouseenter
      function(){
        var current = $(this),
            barColor = current.data('bar-color');
        slideBar.addClass('visible').css({
          'top':'auto',
          'left' : current.position().left,
          'background-color':barColor
        })
      },
      //mouseleave
      function(){
        slideBar.removeClass('visible');
      }
    );
  } else {
    if (isMobile === true) return;
    isMobile = true;
    hiddenMenu.off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(
      // nmouseenter
      function(){
        var current = $(this),
            barColor = current.data('bar-color');
        slideBar.addClass('visible').css({
          'left':0,
          'top':current.offset().top + 60,
          'background-color':barColor
        });
      },
      //mouseleave
      function(){
        slideBar.css({'top':0}).removeClass('visible');
      }
    );
  }
}
$(window).on({
  'resize' : function(){
      sliderBarAnimation();
    },
  'scroll' : function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollTrigger){
      headerBar.addClass('show-bg');
    } else {
      headerBar.removeClass('show-bg');
    }
  }
});
(function(){
  sliderBarAnimation();
  
  hiddenMenu.on('click', function(){
    var current = $(this);
    current.addClass('selected');
    setTimeout(function(){
      current.removeClass('selected');
      burgerCheckbox.prop('checked',false);
    }, 400);
  });
  hiddenMenu.children('a:not([target]):not([href^="tel:"])').on('click', function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!url) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.location = url;
    },400);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro W3", Meiryo, sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body a, body a:visited {
  color: #efefef;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5% 40px;
}

.hidden_menu, .hidden_menu ul {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden_menu ul li, .menu_underline, .header_bar::before {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.humberger, .hidden_menu, .hidden_menu ul, .header_bar, .container {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hidden_menu ul li::before, .header_bar::before, .container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#humberger_check {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger {
  transform: translateY(160px);
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span::before {
  top: 2px;
  transition: top 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333) 0.15s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.22s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
#humberger_check:checked + .humberger span::after {
  top: 6px;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.22s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 6px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 6px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .header_bar,
#humberger_check:checked ~ .container {
  transform: translateY(160px);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .hidden_menu {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
#humberger_check:checked ~ .hidden_menu ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateX(0);
}

.humberger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5vw;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}
.humberger span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto auto -15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color .1s linear .13s;
}
.humberger span::before, .humberger span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.humberger span::before {
  top: 12px;
  transition: top 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}
.humberger span::after {
  top: 24px;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1) 0.2s, transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hidden_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1600px;
  perspective: 1600px;
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.hidden_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.hidden_menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.hidden_menu ul li::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(1)::before {
  background-color: #FA3687;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(2)::before {
  background-color: #21D7A8;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(3)::before {
  background-color: #1E9ED4;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(4)::before {
  background-color: #B0D44A;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:nth-child(5)::before {
  background-color: #A865D5;
}
.hidden_menu ul li.selected::before {
  animation: scaling .4s linear;
}
.hidden_menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.hidden_menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden_menu ul li i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.menu_underline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu_underline.visible {
  height: 3px;
}

.header_bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0 5vw;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
.header_bar::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  opacity: 0;
}
.header_bar.show-bg::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.header_bar h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 26px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B_koKn2rKOkLSXZCakVGZWhOV00);
}
.container::before {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 4vw;
  padding: 0 5vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  font-size: 38px;
}

@keyframes scaling {
  50% {
    opacity: .28;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 680px) {
  #humberger_check:checked + .humberger,
  #humberger_check:checked ~ .header_bar,
  #humberger_check:checked ~ .container {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }

  .hidden_menu {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .hidden_menu ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .hidden_menu ul li i {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .menu_underline {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MENU</title>
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" role="button" title="menu" id="humberger_check" />
<label for="humberger_check" class="humberger" aria-hidden="true" title="menu">
  <span></span>
</label>
<header class="header_bar">
  <h1>SITE TITLE</h1>
</header>
<main class="container">
  <section class="content">
    <h2>3D Rotating Hidden Menu</h2>
  </section>
</main>
<nav class="hidden_menu">
  <ul>
    <li data-bar-color="#FA3687">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-picture"></i>IMAGE</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#21D7A8">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-film"></i>VIDEO</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#1E9ED4">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-music"></i>MUSIC</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#B0D44A">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-headphones"></i>PERSONAL</a>
    </li>
    <li data-bar-color="#A865D5">
      <a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i>SETTINGS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="menu_underline"></span>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 現状の質問だと回答が難しいと思われます。作成したサンプルコードを含めて、再現できるHTMLJSCSSを追記してください。

Comment: keitaro_soさんありがとうございます。

Comment: この追記で宜しでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ｊQueryを使用されていますが、HTMLファイル内でどこにもｊQeuryの本体を読み込んでいる記述がありません。
[Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery)
などを参考に使用するバージョンを決めて読み込むよう記述してやる必要があります。（下記の例はver.1.12.4)
そのあとにご自身で作成されたｊｓファイルを読み込ませてやれば、動作すると思います。

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sugiyama Koichi様　javascriptのコードだけではだめなんですね！</body>の前に新バージョンで記述したところ動作いたしました。有難うございました。返事が遅くなり申し訳ございませんでした。